# Fitting data to logistic function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit world sales data for BEV and PHEV to a logistic growth function.

For an example, I'm using [R-code for Logistic Growth Model of Australian Population in R (by Elise Gould)](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/752_54c50d2916a34e87be430b97c6b5abbe.html)

But with this method I'm getting the error:

> Error in qr.default(.swts * gr) : 
>     NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(xmid, input) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

My data is:

```
EV_temp<-structure(list(Country = structure(c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("Australia", 
"Brazil", "Canada", "Chile", "China", "Finland", "France", "Germany", 
"India", "Japan", "Korea", "Mexico", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Norway", "Others", "Portugal", "South Africa", "Sweden", "Thailand", 
"Total", "United Kingdom", "United States"), class = "factor"), 
Year = structure(1:13, .Label = c("2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), TotalSales = c(1.89, 
2.23, 2.69, 5.15, 7.48, 14.26, 61.33, 179.03, 381.3, 703.65, 
1239.45, 1982.04, 3109.05)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), .Names = c("Country", "Year", "TotalSales"))
```

Code:

```
EV.ss <- nls(TotalSales ~ SSlogis(Year, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = EV_temp)
```

If anyone could point me in the correct direction in solving this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but looks like this is because `Year` is a factor.

Comment: Thanks yes didn't think of checking that. :) code to fix it: EV_temp$Year<-as.numeric(as.character(EV_temp$Year))

Comment: Just change `"2017"), class = "factor"),` into `"2017"), class="numeric"),`